# CSS: stylize word by word within a div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a div:

```
<div class="dxgBCTC" style="">Meal, Extras, Bar
</div>
```

is it possible to give a background to each word so that it looks something like the following image?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH5m9.png)

Comment: Can you change the HTML? A common way of doing this would be to put each word inside its own element (e.g. a span or make the whole thing a list if it is logically a list and so each word becomes an li element) then you can add the background (and the x could be in a pseudo element, depending on exactly what your needs are).

Comment: I can't change the html

Comment: Not without changing the HTML. As A Haworth said, if you can separate each word to its own element it's possible. If you can use JavaScript you could use that to update the HTML and then the CSS can take over

Comment: You could do a split of the content on comma with jquery and then paste it back, wrapping each word in a span element.

Comment: you would have to change the html to accomplish this.  it might be possible to achieve this by knowing some parent elements that the DIV is wrapped in, but that's highly unlikely.  you would need to wrap each word within a html tag and target the css based of those child elements.  `<div class="dxgBCTC" style=""><span>Meal</span>, <span>Extras</span>, <span>Bar</span></div>` and target those span elements by pseudo style:
`div.dxgBCTC span:nth-child(1) { background: red;}
div.dxgBCTC span:nth-child(2) { background: white;}
div.dxgBCTC span:nth-child(3) { background: blue; } `